# Warum hat man das Adverb „darum“ nicht als Konjunktion klassifiziert?

Tags: grammar, adverb, conjunction

*Darum* ist als ein Adverb klassifiziert, aber es verbindet ein Paar von Hauptsätzen.

Beispielweise:

> Der Rasenmäher ist kaputt gegangen; darum habe ich den Rasen nicht mähen können.
>
> „Der Rasenmäher ist kaputt gegangen“ = Erster Hauptsatz
> „habe ich den Rasen nicht mähen können“ = Zweiter Hauptsatz

Die Übersetzung von *darum* lautet *because* oder *therefore,* die beide als Konjunktion klassifiziert sind.

Comment: _Therefore_ ist als Konjunktion eingestuft? Von wem? Das würde mich wundern.

Comment: @chirlu: [therefore - Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/therefore)

Comment: @Yannick Ihmels: Ich lese da _adverb_. :-)

Comment: @chirlu: Oh, ich auch. Habe wohl nur das gelesen, was in Klammern vor den Bedeutungen steht. Es handelt sich also auch hier um ein Konjunktionaladverb, wenn man es so benutzt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wenn es eine Konjunktion wäre, wäre die Wortstellung anders. Beispiel "denn", mit Nummerierung:

> Der Rasenmäher ist kaputt gegangen, **und** [0] ich [1] habe [2] den Rasen nicht mähen können.
>
> Der Rasen ist sehr hoch gewachsen, **denn** [0] ich [1] habe [2] den Rasen nicht mähen können.

Das Verb steht an zweiter Stelle, die Konjunktion steht "zwischen den Sätzen" und zählt nicht mit. In dem genannten Beispiel ist die (korrekte) Wortstellung aber:

> Der Rasenmäher ist kaputt gegangen, **darum** [1] habe [2] ich den Rasen nicht mähen können.

Die andere Eigenschaft eines Adverbs ist, dass es nicht nur zwischen Sätzen wie eine Konjunktion, sondern auch an anderer Stelle im Satz stehen kann:

> ..., und [0] **darum** [1] habe [2] ich [3] den Rasen nicht mähen können.
>
> ..., und [0] ich [1] habe [2] **darum** [3] den Rasen nicht mähen können.

Answer (score 4):

„Darum“ ist nicht als Konjunktion klassifiziert, weil es keine Konjunktion ist. Es handelt sich in diesem Fall um ein *Konjunktionaladverb*.

In deinem Beispielsatz steht das Konjunktionaladverb „darum“ im Vorfeld:

> Der Rasenmäher ist kaputt gegangen, darum habe ich den Rasen nicht mähen können.

Man kann es aber auch ins Mittelfeld verschieben:

> Der Rasenmäher ist kaputt gegangen, ich habe darum den Rasen nicht mähen können.

Man kann deinen Beispielsatz auch so schreiben:

> Der Rasenmäher ist kaputt gegangen und darum habe ich den Rasen nicht mähen können.

oder

> Der Rasenmäher ist kaputt gegangen und ich habe darum den Rasen nicht mähen können.

Ein Konjunktionaladverb ist also ein Adverb, das die Funktion einer Konjunktion übernehmen kann. Weitere Konjunktionaladverbien sind z. B. außerdem, dagegen, daneben, trotzdem, damit.

Answer (score 2):

Das *darum* in deinem Beispiel gehört zum zweiten Hauptsatz und kann in verschiedenen Positionen vorkommen:

> Darum habe ich den Rasen nicht mähen können.
>   Ich habe darum den Rasen nicht mähen können.
>   Ich habe den Rasen darum nicht mähen können.

Jeder dieser Sätze ist vollständig und kann für sich allein stehen. Im Vergleich zwischen dem ersten Satz und den anderen sieht man auch, daß *darum* die Position vor dem Verb ausfüllen kann und *ich* von dort verdrängt.

Wäre *darum* eine Konjunktion, stünde es hingegen immer an der Grenze zwischen zwei Sätzen und würde keine Position im Satz ausfüllen. Außerdem könnte der Teilsatz mit der Konjunktion nicht selbständig stehen.