# What are the rules for using "sodass", "da", and "darum"?

Tags: word-usage, conjunction, rules

I would like to learn the grammar rules for using conjunctions like *sodass*, *da*, and *darum* in sentences such as these:

- Sie hatte keine Zeit mehr anzurufen, *sodass* …
- Ich komme heute später, *da* …
- Ich muss heute lange arbeiten, *darum* …

I have tried to look for websites that might answer my questions, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in the first place, all these words have different meanings. *Sodass* means *so that*, *darum* means *therefore* and *da* means *since, as or because*.

So there are no rules, when to use which one. Maybe I can make it clear with comparing some examples with their english versions:

1. Er stellte die Vase ans Fenster, *sodass* jeder sie sehen konnte.

   English version: He put the vase by the window *so that* everyone could see it.
2. Ich komme heute später, *da* ich arbeiten muss.

   English version: I will come later today *because* I have to work.
3. Ich muss heute lange arbeiten, *darum* kann ich nicht kommen.

   English version: I have to work longer today, therefore I will not come.

Bare in mind that I would split the two parts in sentence 3 into two separate sentences.

Comment: I think it is worth to spend a word on word order in the clause, which differs between _sodass_ and _da_ on the one hand and _darum_ on the other hand. This is because _darum_ is not a conjunction. See https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23733/warum-hat-man-das-adverb-darum-nicht-als-konjunktion-klassifiziert#:~:text=%E2%80%9EDarum%E2%80%9C%20ist%20nicht%20als%20Konjunktion,den%20Rasen%20nicht%20m%C3%A4hen%20k%C3%B6nnen.

Answer (score 0):

## Semantics

- *da* expresses a causal relation and translates to english "since".
- *sodass* expresses a causal relation, but describes an intention or telos. It translates to English "so" or "so, that".
- *darum* translates to English "therefore".

## Grammar

*da* and *sodass* are [subordinating conjunctions](https://ielanguages.com/german-subordinating-conjunctions.html). That means they introduce a subordinative clause, which has the finite verb in the last position:

> Er stellt die Vase ins Fenster, sodass jeder<sup>[Subject]</sup> sie sieht<sup>[Finite Verb]</sup>.

> Jeder kann die Vase sehen, da sie<sup>[Subject]</sup> im Fenster steht<sup>[Finite Verb]</sup>.

*darum* is **not** a conjunction, but a conjunctional adverb ("Konjunktionaladverb"). That means it is an adverb, which can take the place of a conjunction:

> Darum ist er traurig.

> Die Vase fällt herunter, darum ist<sup>[Finite Verb]</sup> er<sup>[Subject]</sup> traurig.

These are [main clauses, which have the verb in second position](https://blogs.transparent.com/german/german-word-order-main-clauses-part-1).

However, *darum* can also be used just as an adverb:

> Er<sup>[Subject]</sup> ist<sup>[Finite Verb]</sup> darum traurig.

It can take the place of a conjunction and introduces a main clause then. In this case, it pushes the subject of the main clause behind the verb, whose position is stable in second position.